# Why is foreman ignoring the .env in Java using Heroku

Tags: java, mongodb, heroku, foreman, procfile

I created .env file at the root of my project with the MONGOHQ_URL in it but after launching foreman (foreman start), I'm still getting null as a value in Java using System.getenv("MONGOHQ_URL").

Anything im doing wrong? Documentation seemed straight forward.

Comment: what you done till ??

Comment: Can you share your .env and Procile, as well as info about your environment? I've used technique before on OS X with a Java app (with a simple `web: java -jar ...`). One basic mistake I made was putting `export` statements in the .env file...